# Grouping data to complete records between each other

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I've a task where I need to clean my data with duplicate records but at the same time fill those cells with nan with the values of the records with the same name for example:

```
id          id2      name   other_n        date       country
1.177.002   nan test_name    nan     8 decembre 1981    usa
1.177.002   A   test_name   ALVA        nan             nan
```

Until now I tried the normal groupby but I don't get the result I expected

```
tst.groupby('name').mean()
tst.groupby('name').sum()
```

The result I'm looking for should be look like this:

```
id          id2      name   other_n        date       country
1.177.002   A   test_name    ALVA     8 decembre 1981   usa
```

Comment: When data are duplicated, can the values in other columns conflict, or is it always guaranteed to be `NaN` or a unique non-null value (per name)?

Comment: @ALollz it's always guaranteed to be NaN,

Comment: Use ‘first’ as your aggregation

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
df.groupby('name', as_index=False)\
    .agg(lambda col: col.loc[col.first_valid_index()])\
    .reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

The final *reindex* is needed to bring the column order back to how
they are ordered in the source DataFrame. Otherwise *name* would be moved
to the first place